# QGraphicsItemGroup List

Tags: qt, selecteditem, qgraphicsitem

I have multiple `QGraphicsItemGroup` drawn in my `QGraphicsScene`. I want to obtain the list of selected `QGraphicsItemGroup`.

I'm selecting using

```
setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
```

The `selectedItems()` function returns a list of selected `QGraphicsItem`.
Is there any alternative to do the same for groups?

**Edit**

I have created a list of `QGraphicsItemGroup` as:

```
QList<QGraphicsItemGroup *> selectionList;
```

I want to get the selected items(groups) in this list.

How do I type cast `QList<QGraphicsItem *>` to obtain `selectionList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) for QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, it states: -

> *The item supports selection. Enabling this feature will enable setSelected() to toggle selection for the item. It will also let the item be selected automatically as a result of calling QGraphicsScene::setSelectionArea(), by clicking on an item, **or by using rubber band selection in QGraphicsView.***

Since QGraphicsItemGroup is derived from QGraphicsItem, I suspect that by default, a QGraphicsItemGroup does not have this flag selected. So, for each group, set this flag and if you only want the groups returned from the rubber band selection, turn off the flags for all the other items.